# SAS: Running macros inside do loop does not seem to work

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to run a series of macros multiple times. To do so, I've built a new macro that has inside of it a do-loop, which is supposed to run "i" number of times, and with each iteration of the do-loop, the series of macros referenced above are supposed to run.

Here is the essence of code (note that the first proc sql essentially takes from a dataset called "DatesRange" and placed a range of dates into the variable "varlist_Dates"; the range of dates within this variable is used for Macro1, Macro2, Macro3).

```
%macro MultipleTimes;

  proc sql noprint;
    select distinct Date
    into :varlist_Dates separated by ' '
    from DatesRange
    order by Date;
  quit; 

  %do i = 1 %to 5;
    %let date = %scan(&varlist_Dates.,&i.);
    %Macro1;
    %Macro2;
    %Macro3;
  %end;

%mend;
```

I'm finding that it **stops at i=1** and never proceeds. I'm completely unclear on why. I've experimented by playing around with removing some macros and keeping others but nothing seems to work. I feel like there may be something more fundamental about my methodology that is off, because there's something I don't know about SAS and about the way a macro inside of a do-loop inside of a macro works.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: check if `i` is used in any of those macros.  I bet it is.  It's probably being changed to something higher than 5 (thus exiting after one loop).

In SAS, when you reference a macro variable that *already* exists, it is defined as having the scope of the most local symbol table that contains it, unless you use `%local` to specify it as local to the current macro.  So if you throw `%let i=1 to 5;` around in multiple nested macros, it will be using *the same &i*.

As an example, see the following code:

```
%let i=A;
%macro outer;
  %put &=i;
  %do i=1 %to 5;
    %put OUTER FIRST: &=i;
    %inner;
    %put OUTER LAST: &=i;
  %end;
%mend outer;
%macro inner;
  %do i=1 %to 5;
    %put INNER: &=i.;
  %end;
%mend;
%put GLOBAL FIRST: &=i;
%outer;
%put GLOBAL LAST:&=i;
```

Notice how `&i` is always the same value.  That's not what you mean, now is it?

Now, on the other hand, `&i` does get a different value in each bit if you do it right:

```
%let i=A;
%macro outer;
  %local i;
  %put &=i;
  %do i=1 %to 5;
    %put OUTER FIRST: &=i;
    %inner;
    %put OUTER LAST: &=i;
  %end;
%mend outer;
%macro inner;
  %local i;
  %do i=1 %to 5;
    %put INNER: &=i.;
  %end;
%mend;
%put GLOBAL FIRST: &=i;
%outer;
%put GLOBAL LAST:&=i;
```

And if you `%put _all_` in INNER you will see this in action.

---

Second: Don't write it this way.  You're going to so much effort, just write it a better way to begin with.

```
%Macro RunMyMacros(date=);
  %Macro1;  *I hope you use &date as a parameter in these and not as a global;
  %Macro2;
  %Macro3;
%mend RunMyMacros;

proc sql noprint;
  select distinct cats('%RunMyMacros(date=',Date,')')
  into :calllist_Dates separated by ' '
  from DatesRange
  order by Date;
quit; 


&calllist;
```

That's far easier to use, troubleshoot, and run, and doesn't require hardcoding the number of valid dates or anything else in it.

Comment: You're right. Thanks so much for pointing that out and providing an explanation as to why and how macro variables work. As soon as I corrected the "i" and made it "x", it worked, because I was using "i" in basically all my other "inner macros". I am looking into more details of your answer and your suggested improvements and will be in touch if I have questions. Thanks again. I am a little confused as to how the proc sql works, but I'm testing it out.

Comment: Each time I define "i" in my Macro1, Macro2, Macro3, do I need to put the pieces of code "%local i" AND "%put &=i" or just "%local i"? I am unclear on the purpose of the "%put &=i",if you have a second to elaborate?

Comment: @user5278831 `%put &=i;` is shorthand notation for `%put i=&i;`  It just prints out the name of the macro variable, and the value stored within it.  The `%put` statement is not necessary, it is just useful for debugging.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. I suspected the same but, yes, I was confused about the slightly different notation than what I was used to!